# How to get "their mailbox is full" Exchange user's tooltip via Outlook COM?

Tags: python, vba, outlook, exchange-server

What I need is to check if Exchange user's mailbox is available.
I am doing it in python (accessing outlook by:

```
import win32com.client as win32
outlook = win32.DispatchEx('Outlook.Application').GetNamespace("MAPI")
```

For that I got used ".Resolved" property checking after connecting to GAL (Global Address List):

```
rec = outlook.CreateRecipient(who)
rec.Resolve()
```

I need clean (without any logging to Exchange server) solution, only by getting Outlook's COM to check the tooltip that is showing when a message is displayed - is it available there?
The full message with the user's full mailbox is:

> "We won't be able to deliver this message to: [x]. Their mailbox is
> full".

I have found so far the method to get OOF, but it's not about my goal.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.ExchangeUser.GetFreeBusy

And also :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/exchangewebservices.mailtips?view=exchange-ews-proxy

Thank you for any advices (in vba or python, please).

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use either EWS for that ([GetMailTips](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/getmailtips-operation) operation) or Graph (user: [getMailTip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-getmailtips?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http))

Comment: have you any clue if exchange server's response could be taken from MS Outlook?

Comment: Not, not using any API exposed by Outlook. EWS and Graph require that you resister your app and authenticate so that you can get an auth token for the calls. In theory, you can patch WinHTTP functions and extract the token from the EWS calls made by Outlook, but you definitely cannot do that in VBA. Redemption (I am its author) can do that through `RDOAddressEntry.GetMailTips` if you create `RDOSession` object ahead of time so that it can intercept and cache the authentication information.

Comment: I cannot use EWS (I am doing client-side script and cannot install Exchange for solely purpose of getting EWS), and I cannot use other apps, just MS Office. If the property of EWS calls result isn't accessible by Outlook COM, then I need to abandon this concept.

Comment: Not using OOM. If you cannot use EWS or Graph, Redemption is the only option that will work in Outlook VBA (or a COM addin). Since Python is running in a separate process, even Redemption won't help you since it cannot intercept WinHTTP calls in another process (outlook.exe)

Comment: Oh, and you don't need to install (?) Exchange to use EWS. Both EWS and Graph are pure HTTP access protocols that can be used from Python (see for example https://ecederstrand.github.io/exchangelib/)